# Regex to clean my Grafana legend

Tags: regex, grafana

I have these name in my grafana dashboard legend:

- stats.gauges.all.cloudwatch.communicationapi.dynamodb.**ca**_communicationapi_restaurantdispatchmethods.**provisioned**readcapacityunits.maximum
- stats.gauges.all.cloudwatch.communicationapi.dynamodb.**es**_communicationapi_restaurantdispatchmethods.**consumed**readcapacityunits.maximum
- stats.gauges.all.cloudwatch.communicationapi.dynamodb.**ca**_communicationapi_restaurantdispatchmethods.**provisioned**readcapacityunits.maximum

And I would like to extract the country and the type of parameter. I've tried AliasByNode but still very long name. Is there any way to get something like:

- ca-provisioned
- es-consumed
- ca-provisioned

Maybe AliasSub can do it but the regex query seems very complex. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this expression to capture what you need.

```
stats\.gauges\.all\.cloudwatch\.communicationapi\.dynamodb\.(\w{2})_communicationapi_restaurantdispatchmethods\.(\w+)readcapacityunits\.maximum
```

It's a bit long but you'll get what you're looking for.

https://regex101.com/r/PE5jY4/1

Comment: how do you return the groups that you have captured back out in the format? ie the regex you provided catches 2 groups but how do you return those two groups as an output

Comment: @KillerSnail Well that depends on what language you're using.